# Why are my promises (running in parallel and running in serial) completing at the same time

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to see the difference in processing time between running promises in parallel and in serial order. But in the below code, I get the output from both functions at the same time. Ideally, the parallel function result should come up much quicker. Is there anything wrong I am doing here.

```
const timeout = 10000

const function1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("hello1")
    }, timeout);
})

const function2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("hello2")
    }, timeout);
})

const parallel = async () => {
    const result1 = function1
    const result2 = function2
    const result = await Promise.all([result1, result2])

    console.log(result)    
}

const serial = async () => {
    const result1 = await function1
    const result2 = await function2
    console.log("result", result1 + " : "+result2)
}

parallel()
serial()
```

Comment: Because you execute them at the same time (at least the same event loop cycle). Remember, `await` only waits for a promise to complete. It does not prevent the promise from being created. You created both promises at the same time so they should in theory complete at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two key things here:

1. Promises don't "run" at all. A promise is a way of *observing the completion* of something that's running, they don't run anything. **You aren't the only one who's confused by this.** :-) It's a very common misunderstanding.
2. Your `function1` and `function2` aren't functions, they're constants containing promises. As soon as you call `new Promise`, your code in the promise executor runs, which starts your timer. The promise executor is called synchronously by the `Promise` constructor to start whatever async operation the promise is going to report the completion of.

This is why you're seeing the result you're seeing: You're starting all of your timers at the same time, so they all fire at the same time. It doesn't matter whether you're *observing* those completions in parallel or in series.

If you want to see the difference, wait to start your operation:

```js
const timeout = 1000; // <== Changed to 1s

const function1 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
// Note the −−−−−−^^^^^−−− change, I've made `function1` actually a function
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("hello1");
    }, timeout);
});

// Note the change, I've made `function2` actually a function
const function2 = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
// Note the −−−−−−^^^^^−−− change, I've made `function2` actually a function
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("hello2");
    }, timeout);
});

const parallel = async () => {
    const result1 = function1(); // <== Calling the function starts the timer
    const result2 = function2(); // <== Calling the function starts the timer
    const result = await Promise.all([result1, result2]);

    console.log(result);
};

const serial = async () => {
    const result1 = await function1(); // <== Calling the function starts the timer
    const result2 = await function2(); // <== Calling the function starts the timer
    console.log("result", result1 + " : " + result2);
};

parallel();
serial();
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* (and `async`/`await` in Chapter 9, and other useful things elsewhere). This confusion about what promises are and how they work is one of the things I tackle there. Links in my profile if you're interested.